# Cosa vuol dire "springare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Milton **springò** con le dita e fece cadere il sandwich nel contenitore.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "springare" in questa frase? Ho cercato questo verbo in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che significa spingare, scalciare o anche balzare, sbalzare. Tuttavia questi significati non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto.

Comment: A naso, fare molla con medio (o indice) e pollice, come si fa con le biglie.

Comment: Sempre a naso, è voce del verbo springare, modellato su _to spring_ (Fenoglio non era estremamente anglofilo?)

Comment: @PoldoSbaffini: In effetti, era un innamorato della  lingua inglese: faceva le traduzione dall'italiano all'inglese per divertimento e il suo romanzo *Primavera di bellezza* lo scrisse prima in inglese e poi in italiano. Ma "to spring" con quale significato?

Comment: Riguardo al significato, sono al 100% d'accordo con egreg

Comment: @Charo un movimento veloce e repetino, quindi "to spring" come "schizzare" (cfr. "schizzare via") o "scattare". Secondo me non esiste una risposta "documentabile" alla domanda per quanto riguarda la lingua italiana. Nell'azione, appena Milton sa di avere una possibilità, mette tutto a posto velocemente e si prepara all'azione.

Answer (score 1):

Credo che sia questo: quando si mette il ditto indice sulla base del pollice, di fatto facendo come la lettera O, come il gesto della mano per dire OK, e dopo fare pressione sul pollice con la unghia del indice, si lascia il indice avanti come ci fosse una molla dietro l'indice.  Questo movimento fa l'indice calciare qualcosa che ne sia di fronte.  Nel testo, lui ha calciato il sandwich in questo modo.  Come ha detto @egreg.

Answer (score 0):

Springare significa "sgambettare", e a quanto pare viene dalla radice germanica *spring* che effettivamente combacia con i commenti.

Questo sito ha un'ottima spiegazione: https://www.etimo.it/?term=springare

Comment: Scusa, ma cosa significa sgambettare con le dita?

Comment: Attenzione, che quel sito contiene le scansioni del vecchio dizionario etimologico del Pianigiani, dei primi del '900, che era “composto da un dilettante (e quindi fatto ... a forza d'intuizione)” (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/linguistica_(Enciclopedia-Italiana)/).